# Marionette.js + Backbone.js detect invalid route and trigger function

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, routes, url-routing, marionette

I have built a web application using [Marionette.js](http://marionettejs.com/) which is basically a wrapper around [Backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/).

**Problem Statement:** I would like to detect invalid routes / URLs and trigger a function that redirects to 404 page.

**What I've tried:**

> Hack #1

add an `*invalid` mapping to one of the controllers of my application as [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6522963/1791667).

***Problem with this approach:***

Not a good and maintainable solution since I have multiple apps with multiple controllers and just randomly adding invalid mapping to any of the controller doesn't sound a resonable solution.

**Code:**
[invalidPageModule](https://jsfiddle.net/inamtaj/hhL2op1y/) + [application.js](https://jsfiddle.net/inamtaj/0o29r4g6/)

> Hack #2

Extend `History` API with [this method](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/issues/308#issuecomment-9482299) but my Marionette infused application does not seem to work on this solution.

Further readings of official documentation of [Marionette](http://marionettejs.com/docs/master/marionette.approuter.html#backbone-history) and [Backbone](http://backbonejs.org/#History) does not explain the concept of how to correctly extend `History` API in Marionette Framework.

---

Following are some related questions on Stackoverflow but none of them explain in detail on how to achieve the required behavior.
*(Please note that I'm a beginner in Backbone / Marionette.)*

- [Routes and controllers in Marionette.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26960126/routes-and-controllers-in-marionette-js)
- [How to detect invalid route and trigger function in Backbone.Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6489141/how-to-detect-invalid-route-and-trigger-function-in-backbone-controller)
- [Is there a way to catch all non-matched routes with Backbone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11236338/is-there-a-way-to-catch-all-non-matched-routes-with-backbone)

Comment: Try doing as done [here](https://github.com/STRML/backbone.routeNotFound/blob/master/backbone.routeNotFound.js) and listen to the event in your app

Comment: @nikhilmehta I have already tried this solution and it doesn't work.

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: @InamTaj Take a look, there is [another way to extend `Backbone.History` here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33155579/186787). Tested, worked for me. (Must admit I don't completely understand why one works and another one does not...)

Comment: Thanks @0x2D9A3 It worked.!